# How to call a function with the same name but inside another shared library without dlsym?

Tags: c, hook

I want to call  fopen() defined in the libc.so from inside my own implementation of fopen. Is it possible to do it without relying on dlsym, dlopen (and also LD_LIBRARY)?

Comment: Not in standard C. Is this a POSIX question, a Linux question, ...? I'd suggest retagging accordingly. And can you elaborate on why you want to do so? Sounds a bit like an XY problem...

Comment: I'm actually an Android programmer messing with NDK. I dont know what do you mean by XY problem, but my goal is to log some calls and call the original function thereafter, so probably a Linux question.

Comment: OK, then the [android] tag is probably a good choice. For XY, see e.g. here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Your use-case sounds like a typical one for `dlsym`, so why don't you want to use it? (Might be unsupported under Android, don't know, if it is, ignore that question :)

Comment: Thank you mafso. I havent tagged it with [android] because apart from the restrictions I've stated in my question I'm just in the C level, not needing to stirring with the NDK's intrinsics :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether that's a good idea, but you could call your own `fopen` something else, e.g. `do_fopen` and write a macro `fopen` that redirects to that function. When calling `fopen` in your wrapper, either `#undef fopen` or place `fopen` in parentheses to avoid macro expansion:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define fopen(fn, mode) do_fopen(fn, mode)

FILE *do_fopen(const char *fn, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *f = (fopen)(fn, mode);

    fprintf(stderr,
        "fopen(\"%s\", \"%s\") == %p\n", fn, mode, f);
    return f;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f) {
        /* do stuff */
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

That trick only applies to `fopen` calls from your own code, not from libraries.